# Together with Jquery and PhoneGap, print out list of table from database

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have follow the document here
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage
I can create a table, however, i don't know how to print them out using list from JqueryMobile, Please give some advice... Thx very much

Answer (score 0):

Here's an [article and sourcecode](http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/10/sample-application-with-jquery-mobile-and-phonegap/) that will show you how everything fits together...

Hope this helps you further!

Comment: sorry, i have tried a long time, but cannot run it, have u run it before?

Comment: what exactly is the problem you are experiencing?

Comment: i setup all php, database.  when I load the index.html, no rows appears. I have tested all php, and it works, it can return json format. Also, I have add two alert() into functiongetEmployeeList(), alert("hello world3!");      alert3 is poped, but alert4 is not, is it the function problem, please help me><
 $.getJSON(serviceURL + 'getemployees.php', function(data) {
 alert("hello world4!");